# Не находит класс, хотя модуль подключен

Tags: php

Вчера нашёл модуль `php_timetravel.dll` для.. не важно для чего.
Подключил вот так:

```
extension=php_timetravel.dll
```

Потом попытался вызвать:

```
if (!extension_loaded('timetravel'))
{
    echo 'Модуль TimeTravel не установлен';
    die;
}

$timeMachine = TimeMachinaFactory::new(TimeMachinaFactory::WORMHOLE_TRANSPORT);

try
{
    $timeMachine->setDestinationTime(strtotime("01 September 2006"));
    $timeMachine->travel();
} 
catch (TimeMachineException $e)
{
    echo 'Не получилось: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Пишет, что:

```
Fatal error: Class 'TimeMachine' not found in D:\WebServer\domains\projectX\sciframework\classes\Controller\Traveler.php : 741
```

Где у меня ошибка??? Может я что-то не подключил?
Помогите, всё работает, а тут застрял. Сроки горят! Инвесторы в ярости :((

**UPD:** модуль действительно подключен:
[image]

И класс вроде как объявлен: http://pastebin.com/EJTHsyJa

**UPD2:** Оказалось, что я неправильно создавал объект. Но теперь новая ошибка:

```
Не получилось: BKW_TRVL_ALERT: possible paradox, use FORCE_BKW to prevent check
```

Но я с английским не дружу, а переводчик ничего толкового не говорит

Comment: а почему подключаешь модуль imap? или у тебя модуль timetravel.
логично, что в imap нет такого класса, он же совсем для другого.

Comment: @alister, не ту строчку с конфига скопировал, сорри. Но модуль подлючен и всё равно не работает

Comment: <?php
$list = get_declared_classes();
print_r($list);
?>

так ты выведешь все объявленные классы

Comment: php -m
покажет все загруженные модули

Comment: попробуйте через phpinfo(); посмотреть подключен ли модуль php_timetravel.dll

Comment: обновил вопрос

Comment: я вижу классы 

    [119] => TimeMachinaTransport
    [120] => TimeMachinaFactory
    [121] => TimeMachinaException
    [122] => TimeTransportException

но не вижу TimeMachine

Comment: @eicto, спасибо! я не внимательно смотрел, но теперь новая ошибка

Comment: у вас парадокс, используйте параметр FORCE_BKW, чтобы предотвратить проверку (какое-то предупреждение, наверное создали старые данные) короче сын убил своего отца в прошлом, это нерешаемый парадокс.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, в гугле бан словил? В мануале, по-моему, достаточно подробно описаны все исключения.

`setDestinationTime` должен принимать время не в виде timestamp-а, а объектом, в котором явно указана эпоха и 42.

Comment: @Bars, @eicto, всё верно. Получилось!